# Cloud function triggered by cloud storage crashes - ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, cloud-storage

When I upload a xls file on CS to trigger the cloud function I get ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!

Could you please help me find out where the problem is?
This is the function:

````
    bucketName = event['bucket']
    file = event['name']
    filePath = "gs://" + bucketName + "/" + file
    print(filePath)

    df = pd.read_excel(filePath, header=0, skiprows=2, engine='openpyxl')
    df.columns = df.columns.str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.replace('#', 'num', regex=True).str.replace('\)|\(', '', regex=True).str.replace(' ', '_', regex=True).str.replace('.1', '', regex=True)

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()
    # Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
    table_id = "project.dataset.table"
    bigqueryJob = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id)
    bigqueryJob.result()

```
````

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the excel file so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh I see.  Thanks for the answer but I rather not share the file because it might have sensitive information for my client.

Comment: The file is .xlsx but type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: If you can provide at least the column names so the community can have a better understanding of the dataframe operations that you are performing.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, the problem was I have two columns with the same name
Thanks!